# clear().sendKeys() twice is failed in protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, webdriver, protractor

I'm testing the AngularUI - input mask,
and here is one part of my code:

```
it('should validate the peopleID', function() {

        element(by.id('pid')).clear().sendKeys("H12333333A").then(function() {
            expect(element(by.id('pid')).getAttribute('value')).not.toMatch("H12333333A");
        });

        element(by.id('pid')).clear().sendKeys("H123333331").then(function() {
            expect(element(by.id('pid')).getAttribute('value')).toMatch("H123333331");
        });
});
```

the error message is :
`Expected: '' to match 'H123333331'.`

another test code:

```
    it('just a little test', function() {

        browser.get("http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/");
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        element(by.css('[ng-click="y = \'(999) 999-9999\'"]')).click().then(function() {
            element(by.name('masked')).clear().sendKeys("999248551a").then(function() {
                expect(element(by.name('masked')).getAttribute('value')).not.toMatch("999248551a");
            });
            element(by.name('masked')).clear().sendKeys("9992485512").then(function() {
                expect(element(by.name('masked')).getAttribute('value')).toMatch("9992485512");
            });
        });
    });
```

the error message is :
`Expected: '(992) 485-5129' to match '(999) 248-5512'.`

```
My Configuration:
protractor 1.6.1 
selenium-server-standalone 2.44.0 
Chrome 40.0.2214.93
IE 11
Firefox 34.0.5
```

the browser executed  `clear()` and `sendKeys()` then executed the expect statement, but it did not insert text into `<input ...>`at the first test so that I got empty text. It did not clear the input value completely at the second test.

It looks like the github issue#1511: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1511
,but the issue said it just happen "firefox only".I've tried moving the focus to
otherside between inserting incorrect text and correct text, just got the same error message AGAIN.

So what am I doing wrong? and thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this work for you? https://gist.github.com/hankduan/418ea946cb5129fe0606. I just tried against a public site and it works.

Comment: It works fine, but I notice that clear().sendKeys() just failed when I test input mask. I add the second test with its error message, maybe "input mask" is the keypoint?

Answer (score 1):

There has been some known issues with masks and different input types (number, date, etc) messing around with webdriver's sendKeys.

To work with mask, the most reliable way I know is using executeScript to set the value directly:

```
browser.executeScript('arguments[0].value = "(123) 456-7890";', element(by.name('masked')).getWebElement());
expect(element(by.name('masked')).getAttribute('value')).toEqual("(123) 456-7890");
```

Comment: if using `browser.executeScript('arguments[0].value = "(123) 456-78ab";', element(by.name('masked')).getWebElement());` the incorrect value will pass through the validation, then I'll get "(123) 456-78ab" instead of "(123) 456-78__".